# Does JMF have support with Xuggler

Tags: java

i am working on a project consisting of sending and receiving streaming multimedia.So,i have installed JMF, but i have seen that JMF has 32 bit library as mine is 64 bit so i wanted to use Xuggler for streaming videos.

Can anyone clarify me about the support of Java Media FrameWork with Xuggler..

Answer (score 2):

Xuggler and JMF are two independent libraries. I dont think JMF 'supports' xuggler

I would advise not to use JMF as it is not under active development, the last release was in 2004! fobs4jmf, QTJ and xuggler would be better options.